# Multipart question - get access to jenkins methods inside an object

Tags: jenkins

I am using the MPL jenkins library to abstract my stages into separate files. Additionally, I wrote a class to further re-use code across multiple similar stages (like all the prep stages, etc).

Having an issue with some common methods not being available inside my object, so I heard I could pass the steps method as an input in my prep stage., what about other methods? Is there an easy to dump the variables higher in the stack, so that I know what to import, or a more convenient way to import them?

Importing steps allows me to checkout and cleanws.

Things I need yet:
withCredentials, usernamePassword, docker, and stash (stash might be part of steps).

Thanks

Comment: See the answer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77151673/13110835) it explains how to pass the pipeline Script Context and achieve what you want.

Comment: looks like THIS might be the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67164725/1255642